No module named ‘helpers.boost’
I was trying to import a file from my code that is in helpers folder called boost.
I’ve tried to import it in all possible forms, but I couldn’t be able to do so. I got the same error every time: No module named ‘helpers.boost’.
Here’s the part of the script that includes the imports:
import httpx, random, time, datetime, json, os, hashlib, fade import webbrowser import sys import helpers.boost import colorama from colorama import Fore, Style import discord from discord import * from discord.ext import commands

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
